# query with Pointer<_User> in Swift Parse SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I have a class called Client and this class have a Pointer<_User>. I'm trying to do that the follow way:

query.whereKey("user", equalTo:currentUser)

But this way, no data returns in my query.

Someone have an idea how can I to do this query?

Comment: Do you have more code to show ? How you launch your query, how to you treat the response.

Comment: I think you need to query in PFQuery(className: "_User") and use includeKey from your Client Table

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the `includeKey` property on your class, which fetched related objects, e.g.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Client")

// Retrieve the most recent ones
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

// Include the user
query.includeKey("user")
```

Source: [Parse iOS Guide](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#relational-queries)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
```

or

```
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "_User", objectId: "\(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)"))
```

Comment: Thanks! query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!) worked very well!